# showlabel: keep all labels within the margin

Tags: showlabels

I use showlabel to keep track of equation labelling AND section labelling.  For various reasons I need the labels to be within the margin of the text, not outside of it.  Depending on which showlabel parameters I use I can keep either the equation labelling or the section labelling to be within the margin, but not both.  Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{amsart}
\usepackage[inline]{showlabels}
\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\label{sec:first}
\begin{equation}
  x^2 + y^2 = z^2
  \label{pythagorean}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

With this setting the section label is within the text margin, but not the equation label.  If I change the showlabel command to

```
\usepackage[right]{showlabels}
```

then the equation label is within the margin, but not the section label.   I have tried e.g.

```
\usepackage[right,inline]{showlabels}
```

but latex only seems to accept for the first option.  What do I need to do to achieve both settings?  THANKS!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an old issue that `showlabels` does not really like left-aligned equation numbers; its documentation states

> [...] this package [...]
> won’t work with the `leqno` option either (at some point it should be
> modified to at least recognise and warn of the conflict in either
> case, though it’s not obvious to me how to do that).

and `leqno` is the default for `amsart`.

I have a hack but I must admit that I haven't really tested it thoroughly, so no guarantees.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage[inline]{showlabels}
\makeatletter
\def\SL@eqntext#1{\rlap{\quad\SL@margintext{#1}}}
% alternative:
% \def\SL@eqntext#1{\rlap{\quad{\showlabelsetlabel{\SL@prlabelname{#1}}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\label{sec:first}
To show the margins just some text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text
\begin{equation}
  x^2 + y^2 = z^2
  \label{pythagorean}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use the commented line you'll avoid the braces around the label (and the annoying warning about undefined font).